# Visa required for an Indian passport holder to visit The Turkish Republic of North Cyprus?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, northern-cyprus

We are group of travelers planning to visit North Cyprus (i.e. the Turkish Republic North Cyprus).

We are taking a flight from New Delhi -> Istanbul (switch flight) -> Ercan International Airport.

Do we need any visa?

Comment: Related info for travellers to North Cyprus https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/790/northern-cyprus-way-to-visit-and-what-problems-can-i-have-with-republic-of-cyp